# CYPRESS: Check every item from list

Tags: html, css, automation, cypress

As you will see in the link with printscreen, I have a list of several transactions and each transaction behaves in a certain way, depending on certain criteria

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFa0Q.jpg

- transactions can be clickable and there should be a trash can, marked
  with the first red arrow and which has in the code the title "Remove
  allocation"
- transactions that can be clickable and do not have a trash present
  (you must jump over them and move on)
- transactions that are not clickable, press and nothing happens and
  here as well, you have to go to the next transaction.

```js
it('Find transaction for refund', function() {
  cy.wait(1500)
  for(let count=7; count<=10; count++) {
    cy.get('.text-center').eq(count).click()
    cy.wait(1500)
    if(cy.contains('Remove alocation')) {
      cy.get('.js-delete').eq(count).click()
      cy.contains('Yes').click()
      cy.wait(1000)
      cy.scrollTo(500, 0)
      count=count+1;
      cy.wait(1000)
    } else {
      count=count+1;
    }
  }
}
```

text-center represent the item that keeps track of which line they are (from 1 to 25) and which must be incremented after each check to move on to the next transaction

- Clickable: [imgur.com/a/XWmOfD2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVgf3.jpg)
- Unclickable: [imgur.com/a/VSwMHwD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWCKP.jpg)
- Dropdown with trash (title "Remove Allocation" is for the trash) [imgur.com/a/Ds7eYKl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whstd.jpg)
- Dropdown without trash [imgur.com/a/kssV1i6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh0Pc.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you get when you directly execute `cy.get('[title="Remove Allocation"]')`. Do you get all the elements?

Comment: The title "remove allocation" is present only in the trash that can be in a dropdown, not in all You can see this : https://imgur.com/a/7nyLPKw  and after the trash with "Void" title, is the trash with "remove allocation"